# why "0.2" converted to double become 2?

Tags: c#

why "0.2" converted to double become 2?

I try below:

```
 string _xx = "0.2";
 double _d = Convert.ToDouble(_xx);
```

but it returns 2

Comment: What is the decimal dot in your locale?

Comment: Running it in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P4OwgG) results in `0.2`, I'm guessing this is a locale problem

Comment: i tried this in a console application and the output was `0.2`

Comment: Or to be more specific - is dot a group separator in your locale?

Comment: Use `Convert.ToDouble(_xx, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Or better use [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) instead. For example: `double.TryParse(_xx, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _d);`.

Comment: `.` (dot) is a *thousand separaror* (not *decimal* one) in your *current culture* that's why the separator is *ignored*: `"123.456,78" => 123456.78`; `"0.2" => 02 => 2`